# does not match format datetimein python

Tags: python

I want to find the difference between two dates

```
def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%d-%m-%Y")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%d-%m-%Y")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)


x = datetime(2022, 1, 12)
y = x.strftime("%x")
xy = datetime.now()

print(days_between(y, xy.strftime("%x")))
```

But this error is coming

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/user/Documents/python/i-bot-website/test.py", line 15, in 
> print(days_between(y, xy.strftime("%x")))
> File "/home/user/Documents/python/i-bot-website/test.py", line 6, in days_between
> d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%d-%m-%Y")
> File "/usr/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
> tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
> raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
> ValueError: time data '01/12/22' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format

```
x = datetime(2022, 1, 12)
y = x.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
xy = datetime.now()

print(days_between(y, xy.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs(d2 - d1)



v = datetime(2022,2,2)
s = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(days_between(v.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),s))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).